# Calculating the mean per country and dummy variable in R

Tags: r, dplyr, grouping

In the following dataset the variables of interest are the country variable, stfdem.rc (satisfaction with democracy) an prtvtbeR (person who voted for a winning party in the main election = 0, person who voted for a losing party = 1; in the extract for Belgium)

The goal is to calculate the average of satisfaction with democracy for the group of winners and for the group of losers. This should be done for every other country in here.

As I am new to R, I do not really know were to start. I would be able to calculate the mean for one country with `aggregate` as I have done for a similar dataset:

```
cntrystfm <- aggregate(x = mean(stfdem), by = list(ESS.ready$cntry.x, ESS.ready$), FUN = mean, na.rm = T)
```

but I am struggling to get how to do it by country AND winners and losers  and have a data frame as an output. I think it could be done with the dplyr package and `group_by` but I do not really get the trick there.

Any hint and help is appreciated! Thank you!

Here is the dataset:

```
    ID cntry.x stfdem.rc prtvtcbeR prtvtcdkR prtvtdeeR prtvtcfiR prtvtcfrR prtvdde2R prtvtaisR prtvtaieR prtvtbilR
1   1      BE         5        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA
2   2      BE         1        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA
3   3      BE         6        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA
4   4      BE         9        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA
5   5      BE         2         0        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA
6   6      BE         7         0        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA
7   7      BE         9         1        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA
8   8      BE        10        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA
9   9      BE         7        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA
10 10      BE         6         0        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA
11 11      BE         6         1        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA
12 12      BE         2         0        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA
13 13      BE         5         1        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA
14 14      BE         7         0        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA
15 15      BE         8        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA
16 16      BE         6         0        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA
17 17      BE         3         0        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA
18 18      BE         5         0        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA
19 19      BE         5         1        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA
20 20      BE         7         1        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA
21 21      BE         3         0        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA
22 22      BE         7        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA
23 23      BE         7         0        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA
24 24      BE         5        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA
25 25      BE         7         0        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA
26 26      BE         1         0        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA
27 27      BE         8         0        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA
28 28      BE         7         0        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA
29 29      BE         5         0        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA
30 30      BE         7        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA
31 31      BE         5         0        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA
32 32      BE         8        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA
33 33      BE         5         1        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA
34 34      BE         6         0        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA
35 35      BE         9        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA
36 36      BE         6         0        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA
37 37      BE         8         0        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA
38 38      BE         3         0        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA
39 39      BE         8         0        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA
40 40      BE         8         0        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA
41 41      BE         7        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA
42 42      BE         8         0        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA
43 43      BE         6         0        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA
```

I have tried:

```
new <- ESS.ready %>% 
  group_by(cntry.x, prtvtcbeR) %>% summarise(mean(stfdem.rc, na.rm = T))
```

And get the following. But it seems not right + I have to do it for every country in my dataset.

```
structure(list(cntry.x = c("BE", "BE", "BE", "BG", "CH", "CY", 
"CZ", "DE", "DK", "EE", "ES", "FI", "FR", "GB", "HU", "IE", "IL", 
"IS", "IT", "LT", "NL", "NO", "PL", "PT", "RU", "SE", "SI", "SK"
), prtvtcbeR = c(0, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
), `mean(stfdem.rc, na.rm = T)` = c(5.62482168330956, 5.94623655913978, 
6.07171314741036, 3.05838393274171, 7.38729508196721, 4.89052437902484, 
4.969836400818, 5.98835616438356, 7.33725247524752, 4.89203539823009, 
3.98091603053435, 6.8457595526561, 5.1180412371134, 5.58132956152758, 
4.49265477439664, 5.45338645418327, 5.91475409836066, 5.72589531680441, 
4.10554371002132, 4.93753123438281, 6.24653739612188, 7.24099378881988, 
4.90344062153163, 3.96885481552468, 3.86030061892131, 7.01158940397351, 
3.60661157024793, 4.78500551267916)), row.names = c(NA, -28L), groups = structure(list(
    cntry.x = c("BE", "BG", "CH", "CY", "CZ", "DE", "DK", "EE", 
    "ES", "FI", "FR", "GB", "HU", "IE", "IL", "IS", "IT", "LT", 
    "NL", "NO", "PL", "PT", "RU", "SE", "SI", "SK"), .rows = structure(list(
        1:3, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 
        15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 
        26L, 27L, 28L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, 26L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
``
```

Comment: You could try `df %>% group_by(country, prtvcbeR) %>% summarise(mean(stfdem))`

Comment: Hmm, does it help to first filter out rows where prtvtbeR is NA?

Comment: When you try the `dplyr` version you say *"And get the following. But it seems not right."* I do not see any problems with it. What seems not right to you?

Comment: @GregorThomas I only get the mean for the two groups for Belgium. Is there a way to do this just with one line of code or do I have to do it for every country?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
out <- df %>% 
group_by(cntry.x, prtvtbeR) %>%
summarise(mean_satisfaction = mean(stfdem.rc))
```

That should give you a dataframe with columns for country, winner status and mean satisfaction for each combination of country and winner status.

Edit: it turns out the winner status for each country is stored in different columns, so to do what I've written above you need to first convert to long format:

```
df %>% 
pivot_longer(cols = starts_with('prtv'), names_to = 'Country', values_to = 'winner_loser') %>%
group_by(Country, winner_loser) %>%
summarise(mean_satisfaction = mean(stfdem.rc, na.rm = TRUE)))
```

Comment: It works at least for Belgium. However, for the other countries it only calculates the mean for the whole country and not by winners. Do you know how to fix that?

Comment: That's strange, it should work equally for all countries. All I can think of is the NAs in prtvtbeR possibly causing problems.

Comment: I guess it is because for the other countries the variables prtvtdeeR and so on would code the winner and loser status.

Comment: Oh, really? That changes things. I'll edit my answer -- you need to first convert it to long format so the winners/losers are all in the same column.

Comment: I mean, I could run the same code for all the 25 countries but I am wondering if there is a way to do it all in one

Comment: No, there's definitely a way to do it all in one. I'm writing it now.